Jest Test Fails with "ReferenceError: PIXI is not defined" in Phaser-CE Project
I am using the phaser-ce version 2.20.0 in my project.
Although being aware of the newer phaser version, I have to stick to the mentioned CE (community edition) version.
When I run a simple test written with Jest, the test suite fails with the following error:
ReferenceError: PIXI is not defined

(PixiJS (commonly referred to as Pixi) is a 2D graphics rendering using within Phaser.)
Here is my setup:
Project Structure:
phaser-jest-project/
│
├── dist/
├── src/
│   ├── index.js
│   └── game.js
├── test/
│   └── game.test.js
├── .babelrc
├── jest.config.js
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js

package.json:
{
  "name": "phaser-ce-jest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --open",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "phaser-ce": "^2.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "@jest/globals": "^29.7.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "expose-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "webpack": "^5.93.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  }
}


webpack.config.js:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
  },
};

.babelrc:
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}

src/index.js:
import 'pixi';
import 'p2';
import Phaser from 'phaser';
import { createGame } from './game';

const game = createGame();


src/game.js:
import 'pixi';
import 'p2';
import Phaser from 'phaser';

export function createGame() {
    const game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload, create, update });

    function preload() {
        // Load assets
    }

    function create() {
        // Initialize game
    }

    function update() {
        // Game loop
    }

    return game;
}


test/game.test.js:
import { createGame } from '../src/game';
import { it, expect } from '@jest/globals';

it('game should be created', () => {
    const game = createGame();
    expect(game).toBeDefined();
});

jest.config.js:
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^pixi$': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/phaser-ce/build/custom/pixi.js'),
        '^p2$': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/phaser-ce/build/custom/p2.js'),
        '^phaser$': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/phaser-ce/build/custom/phaser-split.js'),
    },
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest'
    },
    testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom'
};



Question:
How can I resolve the "ReferenceError: PIXI is not defined" error when running Jest tests in a Phaser-CE project? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
 ReferenceError: PIXI is not defined

      1 | import 'pixi';
      2 | import 'p2';
    > 3 | import Phaser from 'phaser';
        | ^
      4 |
      5 | export function createGame() {
      6 |     const game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload, create, update });

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/phaser-ce/build/custom/phaser-split.js:563:11)
      at Object.require (src/game.js:3:1)
      at Object.require (test/game.test.js:1:1)


What I've Tried:

Ensuring that Phaser-CE is correctly installed and imported.
Checking for any missing dependencies related to PIXI.
Searching for similar issues online but haven't found a solution that works with my setup.


hello, did you follow the [guide on github](dd you follow the guide) and/or  did you check this github-issue? I'm asking since the basic setup seems to work.

@winner_joiner thanks for your reply. I have checked your linked github-issue which indeed looks similiar. I have updated my code and edited the above provided code examples to reflect those changes. However, the error persists. When importing phaser in src/game.js the issue is still that PIXI is not defined. (Specifically, the error occurs in line 563 of the node_modules/phaser-ce/build/custom/phaser-split.js file.)

Well I tried your code-example, and infact it doesn't run. So looked at it, and got it to run with small adjustments (I just looked at the jest part):

installed a virtual canvas so, that phaser can "render":
  npm i --save-dev jest-canvas-mock


removed the phaser, pixi and p2 imports from the index.js file.

In the game.js changed the imports to:
 global.PIXI = require('PIXI');
 global.p2 = require('p2');
 global.Phaser = require('Phaser');


altered the jest.config.js file to match the "imports":
 module.exports = {
     moduleNameMapper: {
         'PIXI': path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/phaser-ce/build/custom/pixi.js'),
         'p2': path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/phaser-ce/build/custom/p2.js'),
         'Phaser': path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/phaser-ce/build/custom/phaser-split.js'),
     },
     //...
  }



This should run your initial demo test (result seen in image below).
(I hope the same change solve your issue.)


Thank you so much for taking your time to help me! Your help is greatly appreciated and it indeed has fixed my issue!

Your Welcome, if it is a interesting question and especially if it a good documented question, I compelled to find an answer. And thank you for accepting my answer and your feedback.
